# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json con descarga Excel

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Dispongo de una descarga de una hoja Excel que es construida con [EPPLUS](https://www.epplussoftware.com/es), al momento de enviar el excel a la vista, para que se descargue, me realiza algo que no llego a comprender por qué:

- Me envía a una vista vacía.
- No se descarga el excel.

En la consola de Chrome me salta esta advertencia:

> **`Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json`**

Las funciones que realizo para descargar el excel son:

### **Vista**

---

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Controlador/Funcion?Condicion1=" + cond1 + "&Condicion2=" + cond2,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            window.location = '/Controlador/Download';
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.error(data);
        }
    });
```

### **Controlador**

---

**Funcion**

```
[Authorize]
[TsVisible]//TypeScript
public ActionResult Funcion(int Condicion1, string Condicion2)
{   
    try
    {      
        //Obtengo los datos de BBDD
        var llamadaFuncionBD = GetDatosConCondicion(Condicion1,Condicion2);
        //Genero el excel
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(memoryStream))
        {
            ExcelPackage Ep = new ExcelPackage();
            ExcelWorksheet Sheet = Ep.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Report");
            Sheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "Campo";
            
            int row = 2;
            foreach (var item in llamadaFuncionBD)
            { 
                Sheet.Cells[string.Format("A{0}", row)].Value = item.dato;
                row++;
            }

            Sheet.Cells["A:AZ"].AutoFitColumns();
            //Lo Guardo en la sesión
            Session["DownloadExcel_FileManager"] = Ep.GetAsByteArray();
            return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return AjaxResp.Error("error", e.ToString());
    }
}
```

**Download**

```
 [TsVisible]
    public ActionResult Download()
    {
        if (Session["DownloadExcel_FileManager"] != null)
        {
            byte[] data = Session["DownloadExcel_FileManager"] as byte[];
            return File(data, "application/octet-stream", "Descarga.xlsx");
        }
        else
        {
            return AjaxResp.Error("error", "No se ha podido descargar el excel");
        }
    }
```

Como se puede observar tengo manejadas las posibles excepciones, no salta ninguna, entonces hace la funcionalidad bien, pero no es el caso.

> **¿Qué puede estar ocurriendo?**

Comment: Al hacer `return Json(...)` el controlador aplica el *Content-type* de la respuesta como `application/json`. Pero no mandas un JSON, sinó un *document*. Tienes que explicitar qué tipo de contenido tiene la respuesta.

Comment: He probado a cambiar la función que construye el excel a void, pero realiza la misma acción, te refieres a eso? No comprendo bien *Tienes que explicitar qué tipo de contenido tiene la respuesta.*

Comment: Perdona que no dé más detalles. Es que tampoco sé muy bien cómo hacerlo (por eso no redacto la respuesta). Pero el mensaje de error viene de ahí. El tipo de contenido se describe en la cabecera de la respuesta HTTP. Deberías poner algo parecido a [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166205/mime-type-for-excel-xml-asp-net-3-5). Y quitar el `return Json(...)` porque entre otras cosas, por dentro pone el *Content-Type* como `"application/json"`.

Comment: Con los cambios que realicé, al cambiar la función a `void`, sería una simple invocacion sin retorno, eliminando la cache hice la prueba y continuaba sucediendo, en la función download especifico un retorno File

Comment: Como es el codigo del action `Download` ?

Comment: Lo puedes observar en el apartado controlador, hay que hacer scroll

Comment: No tienes ningun mensaje de error en javascript? lo puedes ver en la consola del developer tools del browser. Si pones un breakpoint, puedes validar que Session tiene contenido

Comment: No salta ningún mensaje de error en la consola, he puesto puntos de parada pero en visual studio, entra a la función. ¿lo compruebo también desde el devOps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias exportar y enviar el archivo en la misma accion sin tener que redireccionar a otro action

[MVC - Return A File (Excel) From A Controller’s Action Method And Create An Excel Blob In To The jQuery Along With Loader Effect](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/mvc-return-a-file-excel-from-a-controllers-action-method-and-create-an-exce/)

[Export excel file using MVC and JQuery](https://medium.com/@vaibhavrb999/export-excel-file-using-mvc-and-jquery-807559bfadc3)

Puedes recibir directo el archivo en `$.ajax` y generar un link dinamicamente para su descarga

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Controlador/Funcion?Condicion1=" + cond1 + "&Condicion2=" + cond2,
    cache: false,
    success: function (filedata) {
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(filedata.FileContents); 
        var blob = new Blob([bytes], {type: “application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet” });
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = "Report.xlsx";
        link.click();
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.error(data);
    }
});
```

Envias el archivo en ese mismo action

```
[Authorize]
[TsVisible]//TypeScript
public ActionResult Funcion(int Condicion1, string Condicion2)
{   
    try
    {      
        //Obtengo los datos de BBDD
        var llamadaFuncionBD = GetDatosConCondicion(Condicion1,Condicion2);
        
        //Genero el excel
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(memoryStream))
        {
            //codigo
    
    
            var file = Ep.GetAsByteArray();
            return File(file, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Report.xlsx"); 
            
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return AjaxResp.Error("error", e.ToString());
    }
}
```